# HTML5 Form Pattern for 7 or 10 numbers only

Tags: html

I need a pattern for a student ID that must be either 7 or 10 digits long.

```
pattern="[0-9]{7,10}"
```

I got this but obviously this is between 7-10 not 7 | 10

I tried `pattern="[0-9]{7|10}"`, that also does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `^(\d{7}|\d{10})$"`to get exactly 7 or 10 digits.

***Example Snippet***:

```js
document.getElementById('textbox').onkeyup = function (){
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = this.value.length;
};
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Character Count</span>
  <span id="count"></span>
</p>

<form>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" pattern="^(\d{7}|\d{10})$" required />
</form>

<p>Press Enter to check validation</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[0-9]{7}([0-9]{3})?` instead. This sets the base of 7 digits and an optional extra 3 digits bringing up the count to 10.